# Popup from rollover text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a requirement as illustrated below:

Have a html page with some rollover text in a box.

```
Title1
  Description in 1 line
Title2
  Description in 1 line
Title3
  Description in 1 line
Title4
  Description in 1 line
.
.
.
.
.
Title10
  Description in 1 line
```

All these are in a rollover in a box so that all these moves from bottom to top. Now when a user clicks on a title, say title 5, a pop up should be displayed, showing some text contents. I have a button on this popup whereby the user can click. If this button is clicked, then it should fade this popup and a new popup should come (that too having some text fields, allowing user to enter details).

Basically what I need is to have the two pop-ups in the above mentioned manner. Googled, but couldn't find any since first popup should be generated from a rollover popup. Can some one please help me at the earliest.?

Comment: 1) add an onclick, 2) decide on showing/hiding a div or perhaps use jQuery UI dialog